# How to query the count of child records in soql

Tags: configuration

i am having an custom object of Location which has a lookup to account and i am trying to perform the soql query to get the locations which is greater than 1 from the account object , below is the SOQL query can someone see this and suggest me on the same

```
Select id,name, (SELECT id,Name From SVMXC__Site__r ) from Account
```

Comment: Praveena-- Still facing issue?

Comment: @Javanoob its not happening , from location custom object have a look up to the account so 1 account will have more than 1 location .. here is the query i tried Select Count (ID) SVMXC__Account__c from SVMXC__Site__c where SVMXC__Account__c > 1 GROUP BY SVMXC__Site__c

Answer (score 6):

You can use aggregate query

```
Select count(Id) totalChilds, Account__c from SVMXC__Site_c GROUP BY Account__c
```

As suggested by [@javanoob](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/16304/javanoob) you can add limit as well

```
Select count(Id) totalChilds, Account__c 
     from SVMXC__Site_c GROUP BY Account__c HAVING count(Id) > 1
```

Comment: We can add clause having totalchilds > 1 as per op requirement.

Comment: @javanoob yeah good point we can add ..